# TypeORM No metadata for \"MyEntity\" was found

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, datasource, typeorm

I 1. have the following datasource on "app-data-source.ts"

```js
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import { App } from "./entities/app";

export const appDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.CONFIG_DB_HOST,
    port: 5432,
    username: process.env.CONFIG_DB_USER,
    password: process.env.CONFIG_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.CONFIG_DB_DATABASE,
    entities: [App],
    synchronize: false,
});
```

2. Which uses the entity App on "entities/app.ts"

```js
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity('apps')
export class App {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    tenant_id: number;
    
    @Column()
    client_id: string;
    
    @Column()
    legacy_client_id: string;

    @Column()
    user_pool: string;
}
```

3. And the following module that queries the Entity **App**(Shown above on number 2).

```js
import { App } from './entities/app';
import { appDataSource } from './app-data-source';

export class AuthService {
   async getApp() {
     let tenant=  await appDataSource.getRepository(App).findOneBy({
                client_id: clientId
            });
     }
}
```

However I get the following Error.

```json
{
    "errorMessage": "No metadata for \"App\" was found.",
    "errorType": "EntityMetadataNotFoundError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for \"App\" was found.",
        "    at DataSource.getMetadata (D:\\lami-accounts\\dist\\apps\\auth\\main.js:181364:19)",
        "    at get metadata [as metadata] (D:\\lami-accounts\\dist\\apps\\auth\\main.js:185119:40)",
        "    at Repository.findOneBy (D:\\lami-accounts\\dist\\apps\\auth\\main.js:185312:44)",
        "    at AuthService.getAccessToken (D:\\lami-accounts\\dist\\apps\\auth\\main.js:57451:89)",
        "    at handler (D:\\lami-accounts\\dist\\apps\\auth\\main.js:32:27)"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently I was not initializing the connection by calling `appDataSource.initialize();` function before performing the query.‍♂️ Like so.

```js
// initialize
await appDataSource.initialize();
let tenant=  await appDataSource.getRepository(App).findOneBy({
    client_id: clientId
}); 

// destroy the connection
await appDataSource.destroy()
```